# Cannot load model in keras from Model.get_config() when the model has Attention layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm loading a model in keras from a config dict created by some function. I've tried this scheme with many other models without issues, but this is the first one were i'm using `tensorflow.keras.layers.Attention` and i'm getting an Unknown Layer exception when reading from the config.

I know there is an API to serialize and load custom layers using JSON/YAML, but this is a keras layer, am I doing something wrong?

by the way this is using Tensorflow 1.14.0

```py
from tensorflow.keras import layers, models, utils

def my_model(max_len, vocab_size, embedding_dims):
    sequence = layers.Input(shape=(max_len,), name='sequence')
    feature = layers.Input(shape=(1,), name='another_feature')

    x = layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size,
                         output_dim=embedding_dims,
                         input_length=max_len)(sequence)
    out, sh, sc = layers.LSTM(64, return_state=True)(x)
    att = layers.Attention()([out, sh])
    x = layers.concatenate([att, feature])
    model = models.Model(inputs=[sequence, feature], outputs=[x])
    model.summary()
    return model.get_config()

title_max_len = 50
vocab_size = 35000
embedding_dims = 30

config = my_model(
    title_max_len, 
    vocab_size, 
    embedding_dims
)
model = models.Model.from_config(config)  # Unknown layer: Attention
utils.plot_model(
    model, 
    show_shapes=True, 
    show_layer_names=True, 
    to_file='model.png'
)
```

Comment: I can't replicate your issue. The code won't run as is - I get a syntax error from the `in` object (`in` is a reserved keyword) and there's a typo/extra argument in the call to `my_model`. When I correct those the code runs without any ValueError

Comment: @BrendanA. I edited the code snippet and made sure I got the error running it

Comment: I realized that I was running 1.15 when I tested before. Just confirmed that 1.14 fails for me but 1.15 does not give an error.

Comment: indeed 1.14 fails, can you make your comment as an answer to mark this as resolved?

Comment: Just posted. Of course this doesn't really explain why you have a problem at all - the documentation for `tf.keras.layers.Attention` exists for 1.14 and includes examples very similar to yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem exists for Tensorflow 1.14 but it works without any problems in 1.15. If you're able to upgrade then that may be the easiest solution.